# AJV - "standaloneCode is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, ajv

I'm trying to write a 'sign up' validator for my Express backend. I'm using AJV for this. Obviously, I want to export the validator schema as a module, so I'm following [this](https://ajv.js.org/standalone.html#usage-from-code) page from the AJV documentation. However I keep getting: `TypeError: standaloneCode is not a function`

Here's my code:

```
const Ajv = require("ajv")
const ajv = new Ajv({ code: { source: true } })
const standaloneCode = require("ajv/dist/standalone")

const signupSchema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    username: { type: "string" },
    email: { type: "string" },
    password: { type: "string" },
    confirmPassword: { type: "string" },
  },
  required: ["username", "email", "password", "confirmPassword"],
}

const validate = ajv.compile(signupSchema)

const moduleCode = standaloneCode(ajv, validate)

module.exports =  moduleCode
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: General tip: try debugging or console.log-ing what `standaloneCode` is. Maybe the library authors changed it and wrapped it in an object?

Comment: This is a "default" ESM export, you need to use `const standaloneCode = require('ajv/dist/standalone').default` when calling `require`

Comment: Thanks, adding .default worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a mistake in the AJV documentation (https://ajv.js.org/standalone.html). The bundled `standalone` module has ESM style exports, so you will need to explicitly refer to `.default` when using `require`:

```js
const standaloneCode = require('ajv/dist/standalone').default
```